# Replacing values of a file based on a conf file

Tags: linux, perl, shell, unix, configuration

I have a conf file which has the format of variable="value" where values may have special characters as well. An example line is:

LINE_D="(L#'id' == 'log') AND L#'id' IS NULL"

I have another file F which should replace values based on this conf file. For example, if there is line in F
   PRINT '$LINE_D'
it should be replaced by 
   PRINT '(L#'id' == 'log') AND L#'id' IS NULL'

How can I a program in shell script which takes conf and F and generate the values in F replaced.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of what's required leaves lots of gaps, so you'll probably need to tweak this script.  It is a cut-down version of a more complex script originally designed to process makefiles.  That means there is probably material you could remove from here without causing trouble, though I've gotten rid of most of the extraneous processing.

```
#!usr/bin/env perl
#
# Note: this script can take input from stdin or from one or more files.
# For example, either of the following will work:
#   cat config file | setmacro
#   setmacro file

use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Std;

# Usage:
# -b -- omit blank lines
# -c -- omit comments
# -d -- debug mode (verbose)
# -e -- omit the environment

my %opt;
my %MACROS;
my $input_line;

die "Usage: $0 [-bcde] [file ...]" unless getopts('bcde', \%opt);

# Copy environment into hash for MAKE macros
%MACROS = %ENV unless $opt{e};

my $rx_macro = qr/\${?([A-Za-z]\w*)}?/;     # Matches $PQR} but ideally shouldn't

# For each line in each file specified on the command line (or stdin by default)
while ($input_line = <>)
{
    chomp $input_line;
    do_line($input_line);
}

# Expand macros in given value
sub macro_expand
{
    my($value) = @_;
    print "-->> macro_expand: $value\n" if $opt{d};
    while ($value =~ $rx_macro)
    {
        print "Found macro = $1\n" if $opt{d};
        my($env) = $MACROS{$1};
        $env = "" unless defined $env;
        $value = $` . $env . $';
    }
    print "<<-- macro_expand: $value\n" if $opt{d};
    return($value);
}

# routine to recognize macros
sub do_line
{
    my($line) = @_;
    if ($line =~ /^\s*$/o)
    {
        # Blank line
        print "$line\n" unless $opt{b};
    }
    elsif ($line =~ /^\s*#/o)
    {
        # Comment line
        print "$line\n" unless $opt{c};
    }
    elsif ($line =~ /^\s*([A-Za-z]\w*)\s*=\s*(.*)\s*$/o)
    {
        # Macro definition
        print "Macro: $line\n" if $opt{d};
        my $lhs = $1;
        my $rhs = $2;
        $rhs = $1 if $rhs =~ m/^"(.*)"$/;
        $MACROS{$lhs} = ${rhs};
        print "##M: $lhs = <<$MACROS{$lhs}>>\n" if $opt{d};
    }
    else
    {
        print "Expand: $line\n" if $opt{d};
        $line = macro_expand($line);
        print "$line\n";
    }
}
```

Given a configuration file, `cfg`, containing:

```
LINE_D="(L#'id' == 'log') AND L#'id' IS NULL"
```

and another file, `F`, containing:

```
PRINT '$LINE_D'
PRINT '${LINE_D}'
```

the output of `perl setmacro.pl cfg F` is:

```
PRINT '(L#'id' == 'log') AND L#'id' IS NULL'
PRINT '(L#'id' == 'log') AND L#'id' IS NULL'
```

This matches the required output, but gives me the heebie-jeebies with its multiple single quotes.  However, the customer is always right!

*(I think I got rid of the residual Perl 4-isms; the base script still had a few remnants left over, and some comments about how Perl 5.001 handles things differently. It does use `` $` `` and `$'` which is generally not a good idea.  However it works, so fixing that is an exercise for the reader.  The regex variable is not now necessary; it was when it was also recognizing `make` macro notations — `$(macro)` as well as `${macro}`.)*